# Node js+ Error: This socket has been ended by the other party] code: 'EPIPE'

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using nodejs and postgresql

I am try to insert data through ajax call. 
Trying to the following things.

```
1. Insert the record in conversation table.
2. get the conversation table last insert id(primary key).
3. last insert id try to insert other table multiple times.
```

Error:

The query was working good. after insert this data in front end side not working. When i try to refresh the page in front-end side I am getting the following error in terminal **"{ [Error: This socket has been ended by the other party] code: 'EPIPE' }"**

I added my following code.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pg = require('pg');
var client = require('../routes/database.js');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var dateFormat = require('date-format');
var async = require('async');
var today = dateFormat(new Date());



router.post('/conversation/start', function(req, res) {
    //var partyId = sess.userId;
         var partyId = 20;
    var topic = "welcome";
    var msg = "test message";
    var to_user_details = JSON.parse([{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5}]);

    client.query('BEGIN', function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return rollback(client);
        }
        client.query('insert into conversation (party_id , topic, message, created_on) values (' + "'" + partyId + "'" + ',' + "'" + topic + "'" + ',' + "'" + msg + "'" + ',' + "'" + today + "'" + ') RETURNING id', function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return rollback(client);
            }
            var conversationId = result.rows[0].id;
            async.each(to_user_details, addToUsersConversation.bind(null, conversationId), function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return rollback(client);
                }
                client.query('COMMIT', client.end.bind(client));
                res.send("conversation added");
            });
        });

    });

});




var addToUsersConversation = function(conversationId, toUserDetails, cb) {
    client.query('insert into conversation_to (conversation_id , party_id, type) values (' + "'" + conversationId + "'" + ',' + "'" + toUserDetails.id + "'" + ',' + "'" + toUserDetails.type_flag + "'" + ')', function(err, result) {
        if (err)
            return cb(err);
        cb(null);
    });

};
```

Comment: I assume you have found that the error was somewhere in your MySQL connection and it is resolved? Can you share your solution?